# can't create a dynamic array to a struct with a pointer

Tags: c, pointers, dynamic-arrays

I have a struct Person, with a name, id, and number of kids.
I'm trying to create a dynamic array for the names, id and number of kids. Keep getting the error "uninitialized local variable 'name' used"

```
        Person *person;
        printf("Add a person to the game? (0|1)");
        scanf("%c",&dummy);
        scanf("%d",&input);
        while (input == 1)
        {

            person->name =(char*)malloc(strlen(arr));
            if (person->name == NULL)
                return NULL;
            person->id = (int*)malloc(ID*sizeof(int));
            if (person->id == NULL)
                return NULL;
            person->kids = (char*)malloc(kidNum * sizeof(char*));
        }
```

Comment: You'll need to show more of your code, as the problem isn't here.

Comment: Oh, and don't cast the return value of malloc: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc.

Comment: You could start with `Person *person = malloc(sizeof(Person));` to actually *have*  a struct.

Comment: Ignoring some of the errors in your loop, `person->name` won't point to an array of names, perhaps you should allocate an "array" of `Person` objects?

Answer (score 2):

I am not C expert but seeing your code it seems like you are creating a pointer to a struct and then your pointer is not initialized to any thing. This may be the reason for your problem. I am not sure of the proper syntax but try this:

`Person* person = malloc(sizeof(Person));`